# Animate object along animated curve synchronization issue

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, interpolation

I'm trying to animate something like a 3D pen that leaves a trail of filament. The problem is that the trail and the pen-tip are not synchronized.

I approach this by first animating a Bezier curve. In its object properties I set keyframes on the "Start & End Mapping" section.

Then, I use an Empty axes with a "Follow Path" constraint.I set the target as the Bezier curve, and I also add keyframes to the "Offset" attribute in the "Object Constraint Properties".

Then I simply parent a pen-like object to the Empty axes.

I'll attach screenshots of the animation at certain frames and my blend file if it helps make things clearer.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the synchronization?

[Link to blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a-WnME5a5ByBn1onDYpOfrpc1dxSxE-c/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
At first the filament trail is lagging(frame 18/100)

[image]
Then the trail is leading(frame 80/100)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's any automatic way, but you could just create some additional keyframes on the *Offset* value of the *Follow Path* constraint of the empty in order to synchronize its position to the curve tip. Example, here is the current situation at frame 60:

[image]

Change the *Offset* value until the empty synchronize with the curve tip, and keyframe it:

[image]